# When is SqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics() useful?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

What are the problems that calling this method can help with?
Do you ever use it in debugging you data access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page from MSDN has more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h2ahss8(VS.80).aspx). Seems like it contains useful debugging information but I must admit I've never used it.